# java.util.Date from <input type="datetime-local" />

Tags: java, html, spring, date, jstl

I'm using JSTL with Spring and I've got the code:

```
<form:input type="datetime-local" path="startDate" />
```

where startDate is a java.util.Date

How can I get the date and time from the input? Is there a right way or should I get the string from the input and write code to convert it to java.util.Date?

Thanks in advance.

This is my nuevaTarea.jsp:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Nueva tarea</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Nueva tarea</h1>       
    <form:form action="nuevatarea.htm" method="POST" commandName="tareaForm"> 
        <label>Fecha de inicio:</label><form:input type="datetime-local" path="fechaInicio" /><br />
        <label>Fecha de fin:</label><form:input type="datetime-local" path="fechaFin" /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Crear tarea" />
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my TareaForm.java which is the command class:

package web.controller;

import java.util.Date;

public class TareaForm {

```
private Date fechaInicio;
private Date fechaFin;

public Date getFechaFin() {
    return fechaFin;
}

public Date getFechaInicio() {
    return fechaInicio;
}

public void setFechaFin(Date fechaFin) {
    this.fechaFin = fechaFin;
}

public void setFechaInicio(Date fechaInicio) {
    this.fechaInicio = fechaInicio;
}
```

}

And, this is my controller nuevaTareaController.java:

package web.controller;

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;

public class nuevaTareaController extends SimpleFormController {

public nuevaTareaController() {
    setCommandClass(TareaForm.class);
    setCommandName("tareaForm");
}

    @Override
    protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    return (TareaForm)super.formBackingObject(request);
}   

   @Override
   protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command, BindException bindException)
    throws Exception {

    // Do something with (TareaForm)command
    return new ModelAndView(getSuccessView());
  }

}
```

This is the config of the controller in my dispatcher-servlet:

```
<bean class="web.controller.nuevaTareaController">
    <property name="formView" value="nuevaTarea" />
    <property name="successView" value="tareaCreada" />
    <property name="gestorTareas" ref="tareas" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Spring form has no attribute type, it defaults to `type=text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a PropertyEditor to convert from String to Date.  Spring has [already taken care of this](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/11/17/spring-3-type-conversion-and-validation/) for you.  The end result should be a java.util.Date.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I've edited my question because I don't understand completely your answer. As you can see, I'm not using annotations nor PropertyEditor nor any validator. Are you suggesting to me that there is an annotation which converts the HTML5 Date String format to Date? An example of HTML5 Date string is 1985-04-12T23:20:50.52 from http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime-local.html

Comment: FYI: The HTML 5 datetime-local format lacks the seconds, so yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm So the string is not in the ISO yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ format Spring / Jackson handle out of the box  so something along the lines of: @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")